# Value of Property is showing null

Tags: c#, properties

I have a static class IDGENERATOR.
it will generate id automatically like CurrentYear-CurrentMonth-Serial.
Ex. 2018-02-00001
When month changed serial number set to 00000.

I did this.

```
static class IDGENARATOR
{
    private static int serial_no;
    static DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    static int month = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Today.Month);


    public static string generate;

    public static string Generate
    {
        get
        {
            return generate;
        }
        set
        {
            serial_no++;
            generate = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", dt.Year, month.ToString("00"), serial_no.ToString("00000"));

            if (month < DateTime.Today.Month)
            {
                serial_no = 00000;
            }
            serial_no += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

it will generate id and store in generate variable.

when i call Generate from another class and print it i shows null.

```
ID = IDGENARATOR.Generate;
```

What is the error?

Comment: Was the property ever set?

Comment: no. actually it will generate automatically.
i thought it will works, but it didn't . 
i have no idea how to do that

Comment: How?  `ID = IDGENARATOR.Generate;` will "return" the value of generate.

Comment: Think about what's the value of `generate` if `IDGENARATOR.Generate.Set` is never called

Comment: Get rid of your get-set.  Just turn this into a function that returns a value.

Comment: can you suggest me how to generate id like explained. i have not so much idea about property.

Comment: i have an assignment , generate should be property. So, i need to make it as property . I knoen that when a property called first set called and then get. and so i did this

Comment: Then make it a read-only property.  Move the "set" stuff to the get part and return the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're already aware of this so forgive me if I'm wrong, but there is a difference between *generate* and *Generate* in your code. The first is a static field and the second is a static property. A field stores whatever value you put in it and a property runs the get/set code when it is read/written.

Unless you specify an initial value, a string type field will be null initially which is the case with the *generate* field. Since *generate* is null, reading *Generate* will also return null as it's get code does nothing but return the value of the *generate* field. As it is currently, the only way your code will work is if *Generate* is written first which will then assign a value to *generate* and allow the subsequent reading of *Generate* to return something other than null

You might want to consider re-writing the code along the lines of:

```
static class IDGENERATOR {

  public static string Generate {
    get {
      string id;

      id = ..... // Do the work of generating a new ID here
      return(id);
    }
  }

}
```

With this type of code, every time the *Generate* property is read it will do the work of creating a new serial number

Regardless, there are other issues here too. You need to save state in such a way that it remembers the serial number and month in-between sessions (since your code will not run forever) and this is another question entirely

You should also consider enclosing the body of the get statement in a lock statement to prevent errors if multiple threads access the property at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Guid class to generate a universal id as well.
To do it, you may code:

```
public static string GetSerial()
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
```

This code will return something like this:
87132860-7bb3-41df-83b7-2f99b04aafa0 and each time will be a different serial.